# Are tag-specific badges available in public betas?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, tags

I was poking around the tag statistics tonight, and noticed that Brian Campbell has [132 votes](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/recommendations/topusers) for the **Recommendations** tag, but no badge for hitting 100 upvotes in the category.

Are these badges available in public beta?  If so, am I miscalculating something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**,

He has not collected votes in 20 different questions as required.

From https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags

> You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

Also, I collected the badge for `dnd4.0` in the RPG SE beta.

Comment: interesting, thanks for the clarification.  When I did a mouse-over on my `sql` badge on Stack Overflow, it made no mention of the 20 different questions.  Where did you get that answer from?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - added link, sorry for the ommision

Comment: Ludwing -- thanks!  Somehow, I had never seen that tab before.